# Question on C++ constructor exception safety

Tags: c++, exception

From "Exceptional C++", page 27, the author was talking about this code of Stack:

```
template< typename T>
class Stack {
public:
  Stack();
  ~Stack();
private:
  T* v_;
  size_t vsize_;
  size_t vused_;
};

template<typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack() :v_(0), vsize_(10), vused_(0) {
  v_ = new T[vsize_];
}
template<typename T>
Stack<T>::~Stack() {
  delete[] v_;
}
```

And on pages 27 and 28, it states that this is not going to leak when `T`'s constructor throws. To quote the book:

> Second, T's default constructor, which might throw anything at all, in which case any objects that were constructed are destroyed and the allocated memory is automatically guaranteed to be deallocated via operator delete[])()

However, I don't understand the reason why `T`'s destructor and `delete[]` are called automatically when `T`'s constructor throws. There is no `try`/`catch` here, and the destructor won't be triggered for a half-done constructor. My understanding is we need to clean up our own mess in the constructor, and I don't see it done here.

I double-checked in my own gcc10 environment and I don't see `T`'s destructor called when it's thrown. For example, if I use below `Thrower` to create a stack, I don't see the destructor line printed.

Am I missing something?

```
int created = 0;
class Thrower {
public:
  Thrower() {
    if (created++ == 2) {
      throw overflow_error("overflow!");
    }
  }
  ~Thrower() {
    cout << "destructor called";
  }
};
```

Comment: `Thrower` destructor should have `<< endl;` as the implementation is not required to flush incomplete lines of output

Comment: Note: the quote doesn't say that your destructor will be called.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I missing something?

Yes, this part of the quoted text:

> Second, T's default constructor, which might throw anything at all, in which case **any objects that were constructed** are destroyed and the allocated memory is automatically guaranteed to be deallocated via operator delete[])()

When creating an array using a `new[]` expression, the memory for the array is allocated, and then the elements are constructed in order within that memory.  If any element's constructor throws, any *already constructed* objects will get destructed automatically, but not the object whose constructor threw, and then the memory for the array is deallocated automatically.  This all happens inside of the `new[]` expression, which is why you don't see any code for it.

And since there is no `try`/`catch` in `Stack`'s constructor, any exception thrown by `T`'s constructor will continue to propegate up the call stack after the array creation is aborted, thus aborting `Stack`'s constructor (so `Stack`'s destructor will not be called), and so on until the exception is caught, or the process terminates if not caught.

Comment: Additionally: It's important to note that the cleanup is for the _expression_, not the _constructor_. So: If there's _two_ `new` expressions, the second can throw and the first one will then leak.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the specification of the `new[]` expression is that if one of the `T` constructor throws, then the implementation must destroy all of the earlier `T` and free the storage obtained.

It's nothing to do with the `Stack` ; you could observe this behaviour in a program by making some class that sometimes throws in the constructor, and doing `int main() { try { new Myclass[100]; } catch(...) {} }`

Note that you should have a matching `catch` handler in order to observe the behaviour -- an exception that would be uncaught is allowed to terminate the program without performing any intermediate object destruction.

Comment: even if he catches the exception?

Comment: @DaviMendesDev Yes, the freeing of old objects will complete before execution enters the catch handler.  (But if there is no handler, the program is allowed to terminate without freeing the old objects)

Comment: Yes!! after catching the exception I was able to see the destructor of T called!